# Populate data in textfield from button action of another class

Tags: ios, objective-c

my problem is that i have a textfield on my viewcontroller which should be get filled by user and to provide options to fill the textfiled there is a arrow button front of textfield. Clicking on it open a new viewcontroller with a list of options. So when the user click on any option from that viewcontroller the data will automatically fill in that textfield and user return on previous viewcontroller. And i can not use preprefor segue in it so please provide an answer. If i am missing something let me know i ll comment or edit.

Comment: use uitableview call back or delegate

Comment: use NSNotifiactionCenter post notifecation and add observer method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSNotificationCenter` to fill back your `UITextField`. Add Observer to your first `viewController` `class` where you want to fill the `textField`. Add this lines of code in `viewDidLoad`-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fillMyTextField:) name:@"fillMyTextField" object:nil];
```

than add `selector` method in same class--

```
- (void)fillMyTextField:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    self.myTxtField.text = (NSString *)notification.userInfo;
}
```

Now in your other `viewController` `class` where you select data for `textField`. Write the below code in method where you select your data like-

```
- (IBAction)selectDataAndBackToPreviosVC:(UIButton*)selectedOptionBtn {

     id object=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",selectedOptionBtn.titleLabel.text];

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fillTextField" object:nil userInfo:object];

     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

in this I have used `navigationViewController` which use `Push` and `Pop` `viewControllers` and i have some `UIButton` in option selection `viewController`. I'm passing button title which is options to `myTextField` on `IBAction`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fillTextFieldAction:) name:@"fillTextField" object:nil];


- (IBAction)fillTextFieldAction:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    textField.text = (NSString *)notification.object
}

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fillTextField" object:nil userInfo:textFieldInfo];
```

Comment: in which class i use this?

Comment: see @Bhargav B. Bajani answer he clearly said the what i posted above

Answer (score 0):

In class where textfield Define Below method (add notification observer)

in viewDidLoad

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fillTextField:)
                                                 name:@"fillTextField" 
                                               object:nil];

- (IBAction)fillTextField:(NSNotification *)sender 
{
    textField.text = (NSString *)notification.object
}
```

In Another class where u select date set below method in date selection action

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"fillTextField" object:nil userInfo:textFieldInfo];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification:

In View controller ofTextField add this

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{

//Your rest of code then below statement

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(receiveTextNotification:) 
            name:@"TestNotification"
            object:nil];
}

- (void)receiveTextNotification:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"%@ updated", [notification userInfo]);
}

- (void) dealloc
{
     // If you don't remove yourself as an observer, the Notification Center
    // will continue to try and send notification objects to the deallocated
    // object.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In View controller of Button, on button click add this:

```
- (IBAction)fillTextFieldAction: (id) sender    {
         // All instances observing the `TestNotification` will be notified
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNotification" object:self userInfo:text];   //Object here can be any changed value .
    }
```